# chaining using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, chaining

```
<script>
var elms = document.getElementById("contentWrapper").getElementsByClassName("pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette");
console.log(elms);
for (var i=0; i<elms.length; i++) {
console.log(elms[i]);
}
</script>
```

When I try using getElementsByClassName I see no logs related to the second console.log message. 
The first console.log gives me

> [item: function, namedItem: function] 0:
>   div#head_01Bd000000WqJ9k_ep.pbSubheader.brandTertiaryBrd.tertiaryPalette
>   head_01Bd000000WqJ9k_ep:
>   div#head_01Bd000000WqJ9k_ep.pbSubheader.brandTertiaryBrd.tertiaryPalette
>   length: 1
>   **proto**: HTMLCollection

how to I further drill down into the head_01Bd000000WqJ9k_ep and get the firstchild of the class pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette

Someone please correct me if I am not chaining this correct. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll("#contentWrapper .pbSubheader, #contentWrapper .brandTertiaryBrd, #contentWrapper .tertiaryPalette")` but be aware that this function isn't supported in IE7 and lower.

Comment: getElementsByClassName isn't even supported in IE8, so that's probably not an issue.

Comment: nope I get length of the querySelectorAll value as 0. Is there a way to find if an inner image tag which is grand grand child of the contentwrapper ID in DOM.

Comment: I had the query changed some seconds ago, maybe you had the older version.

Comment: How do I further drill down into this Queryselector results. I have 2 divs I see in my result from QuerySelecotr.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `getElementsByClassName("pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette");`
You can specify only one class, like this:

```
getElementsByClassName("pbSubheader");
```

Comment: Why do I see the classname as pbSubheader brandTertiaryBrd tertiaryPalette. Now I see Item [] array having the same head_01Bd000000WqJ9k_ep. I want to drill down and disable the first image child in the class, how do I do this